# grouping values with diferent values in columns using java lambda

Tags: java, for-loop, lambda

I have this Object:

QuoteProductDTO  with three columns ( name, value1, value2)

```
    List<QuoteProductDTO> lstQuoteProductDTO = new ArrayList<>();

    lstQuoteProductDTO.add( new QuoteProductDTO("product", 10, 15.5) );
    lstQuoteProductDTO.add( new QuoteProductDTO("product", 05, 2.5) );
    lstQuoteProductDTO.add( new QuoteProductDTO("product", 13, 1.0) );
    lstQuoteProductDTO.add( new QuoteProductDTO("product", 02, 2.0) );
```

I need to get a consolidate ( a new object QuoteProductDTO ):

the firts column name,I have to get the first value "product".

the second one (value1) I have to get the biggest value 13.

and third column I heve to get the sum of all values 20.

Comment: Which language are you using? Java? What do you mean by "one line"? Do you need the answer printed on one line? In your title you mention lambda, does the solution need to be written with a lambda?

Comment: yes... it's java. I'm doing using for. but if is possible do that w/ lambda i prefer . I need a new QuoteProductDTO with consolidate values.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes the current data provided and generates a new object with the required data.  It uses the `Collectors.teeing()` method of Java 12+

Given the following data:

```
        ArrayList<QuoteProductDTO> lstQuoteProductDTO = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<QuoteProductDTO> nextQuoteProductDTO = new ArrayList<>();

        // empty Quote for Optional handling below.
        QuoteProductDTO emptyQuote = new QuoteProductDTO("EMPTY", -1, -1);

        lstQuoteProductDTO.add(
                new QuoteProductDTO("Product", 10, 15.5));
        lstQuoteProductDTO.add(
                new QuoteProductDTO("Product", 05, 2.5));
        lstQuoteProductDTO.add(
                new QuoteProductDTO("Product", 13, 1.0));
        lstQuoteProductDTO.add(
                new QuoteProductDTO("Product", 02, 2.0));
```

You can consolidate like you want into a new instance of QuoteProductDTO.

```
        QuoteProductDTO prod = lstQuoteProductDTO.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.teeing(
                        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator
                                .comparing(p -> p.value1)),
                        Collectors.summingDouble(
                                p -> p.value2),
                        (a, b) -> new QuoteProductDTO(
                                a.orElse(emptyQuote).name,
                                a.orElse(emptyQuote).value1,
                                b.doubleValue())));

        System.out.println(prod);
```

Prints

> Product, 13, 21.0

You can also take a list of lists of different products and put them in a list of consolidated products.  Add the following to a new list and then add those to a main list.

```
        nextQuoteProductDTO.add(
                new QuoteProductDTO("Product2", 10, 15.5));
        nextQuoteProductDTO.add(
                new QuoteProductDTO("Product2", 25, 20.5));
        nextQuoteProductDTO.add(
                new QuoteProductDTO("Product2", 13, 1.0));
        nextQuoteProductDTO.add(
                new QuoteProductDTO("Product2", 02, 2.0));

        List<List<QuoteProductDTO>> list = List.of(
                lstQuoteProductDTO, nextQuoteProductDTO);
```

Now consolidate those into a list of objects.

```
        List<QuoteProductDTO> prods = list.stream().map(lst -> lst.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.teeing(
                        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator
                                .comparing(p -> p.value1)),
                        Collectors.summingDouble(
                                p -> p.value2),
                        (a, b) -> new QuoteProductDTO(
                                a.orElse(emptyQuote).name, 
                                a.orElse(emptyQuote).value1,
                                b.doubleValue()))))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

         prods.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

> Product, 13, 21.0 
>   Product2, 25, 39.0

I created a class to help demonstrate this.

```
class QuoteProductDTO {
    public String name;
    public int value1;
    public double value2;

    public QuoteProductDTO(String name, int value1,
            double value2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + ", " + value1 + ", " + value2;
    }
}
```